# Almost fixed point property

Tags: smooth-manifolds, fixed-point-theorems

Let $X$ be  a  Hausdorff topological  space with the following  property:

> For every continuous  function $f:X\to X$, there is  a  finite  subset $S\neq \emptyset$ of  $X$ with $F(S)\subset S$

Does this implies that: either $X$ is  a  finite set or $X$ has the  fixed point property?

What  about if $X$ is  a  manifold? Does the  above  condition implies FPP for $X$?

**Edit:** According to the interesting example of Alex to the previous  version of  question, we ask what about if we require $X$ to be connected?

Answer (score 7):

Answer to the first question: "no"; take $X=\{0\}\cup\{1/n\,|\,n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: very nice example But why you need to two copies?I think one copy is sufficient, not?

Comment: With one copy it has fixed point property: the only limit point is always fixed.

Comment: I don't understand why, with only one copy, the limit point has to be fixed.  Why couldn't $f$ map $1$ to $\frac12$ and map everything else to $1$?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right: if the image is finite, the limit point does not need to go to a limit point. Then, indeed, one copy is enough: either $0$ is fixed or image is finite and this image is $S$.

Comment: I think it still works (by considering several cases, with images infinite/finite), but one copy is indeed easier, so I've edited.